# PHP, checking data exist or not from webserver API

Tags: php, html, json

I given an API LINK and some php codes to my html page. The html page contains information that user input that stored in a database. The API link that sent to my html is a link that look like this `"https://nex.web.id/-------/all.php?q=4"` and it cotains JSON of user input. From the server side, the server side do the `total` and `percentage` calculation and then send it to client side which is what i'm working on right now, i just need to do something like showing the number. The problem is, some users might not choose a certain option at all (e.g. All users are `Male`) then the not choosen option doesn't appear at the JSON as `"total": "0", "percentage": "0"`. Now what i have to do is check if a data/field doesn't exist, it will show total of 0 and percentage of 0.

Here is the JSON snippet looks like from the API LINK:

```js
[
  {
    "qno": "5",
    "qdesc": "Male",
    "total": "10 Person",
    "percentage": "100%"
  }
]
```

In that case, every respondences are male, the total and percentage of female should be 0 (it doens't exist/stored). Here is the html form snippet:

```html
<form action="http://api.nex.web.id/xxxx/all.php" method="post" target="" id="surveyForm">
<label>5. Gender</label>
    <br>
      <input type="radio" name="p5" value="Male"> Male <br>
      <input type="radio" name="p5" value="Female"> Female <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">click</button>
```

And the page for showing result snippet:

```html
<?php  
  function get_data($url) 
  {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
  }
  $data=get_data('https://nex.web.id/xxxxx/all.php?q=4');
  $dt=json_decode($data);
  //echo $data; 
?>

<label>5. Gender</label>
<br>
<h4> Male
  <?php echo $dt[0]->total;?> (
  <?php echo $dt[0]->percentage;?>)</h4>
<h4> Female
  <?php echo $dt[1]->total;?> (
  <?php echo $dt[1]->percentage;?>)</h4>
<!--check and show 0 and 0% if doensn't exist-->
<br>
```

Can anyone help me figure this out, please? please let me know if more snippets are needed.

Sorry for my bad english, i'm really need to solve this problem very soon.

Comment: I think a conditional statement like `echo (isset($dt[1]) ? $dt[1]->total : "0");` might be what you need, although I'm not convinced I have correctly understood the question

Comment: if users never submitted `female`, then the database will not have `female` and the JSON also doesn't have `female`, but i have to check if it is exist or not, and if it is not i have to put 0 to the HTML.

Comment: Yes well my suggestion should do that for you. Try it. The syntax is just like a condensed `if` statement

Comment: Thanks, i will try

Comment: how to determine the index `$dt[number]`  if data doesn't exist in JSON? thanks again in advance =)

Comment: well from your the way your code is written I assumed you were always anticipating the Female would be in $dt[1]. Is that not the case?

Comment: ooh i see, So we can set an unused number as their index?.

Comment: my code checks whether the index 1 is populated or not. If it's not populated, it prints 0. If it does exist, it prints the content of the "total" property inside the object at that index. It doesn't set anything in the array, it just checks what's there.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand the question the JSON array returned from the API may contain one element (e.g. just for mail) or two elements (for male and female).

Just accessing the 1st or 2nd element and assuming it contains the data for male / female may not work. (see `echo $dt[1]->total;`)

Instead I recommend to go through each element of the `$dt` array (e.g. with a `for each` loop), check for the value of the `qdesc` property, and fill a 2nd array accordingly. Then use that 2nd array for the output.